# What is the meaning of the phrase in the following sentence,in bold?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

> House prices in many parts of the world have been booming for **the better part of two decades.**

Comment: tbp, your question is bordering "off-topic" - please always check with a dictionary first. In this case we are talking about a set phrase, where slightly other rules apply, but still it is recommended to give at least an own attempt or indicate what you understood so far. I suggest you take the [tour] and check out our [help]. Welcome to the site!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**the better part of [time frame]** is a set phrase meaning *the majoity of [time frame]* or *more than half of [time frame]*.

See [The Free Dictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/the+better+part+of) for example.